# MissingAuthenticationTokenException ("Missing Authentication Token") from CognitoIdentityProviderClient::adminCreateUser()

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I have a working implementation of the AWS PHP SDK. Operations like `$client->getUser()` are working, but `$client->adminCreateUser()` and others are not working.

When I call `$client->adminCreateUser([...])`, it results in:

```
Error executing "AdminCreateUser" on "https://cognito-idp.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://cognito-idp.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"__type":"MissingAuthenticationTokenException","message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
 MissingAuthenticationTokenException (client): Missing Authentication Token - {"__type":"MissingAuthenticationTokenException","message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

Line **191** in **/var/www/project/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/WrappedHttpHandler.php**

Similar services evoked from CLI (e.g `cognito-idp admin-create-user`) with the exact same credentials are working.

What is causing this?

---

#### Example Details

My environment:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Apache 2.4.29
- PHP 7.3
- aws/aws-sdk-php 3.92.3

.aws/credentials

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=XXXX
aws_secret_access_key=XXXX
```

*I am using my developer credentials*

Example code:

```
$client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'ap-southeast-2',
    'credentials' => false, // Set to false to allow roles provisioned to our EC2 instances
]);

$result = $client->adminCreateUser([
    'DesiredDeliveryMediums' => ['Email'],
    'MessageAction' => 'RESEND',
    'TemporaryPassword' => 'TemporaryPassword1234',
    'UserAttributes' => [
        ['Name' => 'email', 'Value' => 'mailbox@domain.tld'],
    ],
    'UserPoolId' => 'ap-southeast-2_XXXX',
    'Username' => 'mailbox@domain.tld',
]);
```

Comment: so i am guessing you have already been to this link but, i thought i would leave it here for completeness https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminCreateUser.html

Comment: Just a query: Is only AdminCreateUser failing in PHP, or are other Cognito Admin APIs failing too? It looks like you are getting this error due to the AWS SDK for PHP not set up properly, and it has nothing to do with Cognito.

Comment: All admin operations that I try fail in the same way, as well as operations like `listUserPools`, but operations like `initiateAuth` and `respondToAuthChallenge` work fine. Can you suggest what set up issue might cause that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove `'credentials' => false` from your `CognitoIdentityProviderClient` configuration.

The `adminCreateUser()` operation requires a signed request (unlike operations like `signUp()`, which is why `signUp()` would work with an unsigned request but `adminCreateUser()` and other operations that require developer credentials won't)

**From the AWS Docs**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-cognito-idp-2016-04-18.html#admincreateuser says

> AdminCreateUser requires developer credentials.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_configuration.html#credentials says

> Pass false to use null credentials and not sign requests.

*A request needs to be signed to provide developer credentials.*