# Cognito - adminCreateUser with no/yes credentials

Tags: amazon-cognito

I use cognito as rest api, but when I create user in cognito, so I create an API for FE to send to BE, then BE will use Cognito and send to it

- When I use signup function, it run ok but it send a code to email
- When I use adminCreateUser, it return "MissingAuthenticationTokenException", msg "Missing Authentication Token", although I set "credentials" true and false, please help me

My expectation is sending an email code when user login and not send when admin create user, and send mail code could be turned on/off by code

Comment: Does this answer your question?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55896967/missingauthenticationtokenexception-missing-authentication-token-from-cognit

Comment: @eli6, I have done this, but I got a stuck right now. I created a user by adminCreateUser, a update the password,  so user now have account status is "CONFIRMED". My expectation is to use login logic,  when I call the api resendConfirmationCode, user will get their code in their email, => FE send code to BE => so BE send code to cognito to verify this code, but I donw know what function to check the code, it show ""User cannot be confirmed. Current status is CONFIRMED